# What is the best way to paginate redshift queries?

Tags: pagination, amazon-redshift

What is the best way to paginate redshift query results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY N LIMIT N OFFSET N`

Comment: Querying large amounts of data is exactly what Redshift is for, but I think you mean it's not designed to be used in the same way as a traditional database - the typical use case for an MPP system like Redshift is aggregating values over large tables, not returning individual rows.

Comment: @Nathan exactly, if we talk about pagination it means returning lots of individual rows

Comment: @Nathan we actually aggregate data in Redshift then pull that data back into our application for segmenting players, obviously batch processing (using pagination) is required to avoid running out of memory (resultset would be too large).