# Spring boot jpa + Redshift - pagination throws query syntax error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-redshift, spring-graphql

I am using creating a service in Spring boot Graphql, where I am using JPA to contact Redshift database. Regular queries run fine. However when I introduce pagination then I get query syntax error from Redshift database.

Below is my controller method

```
@QueryMapping("allProductsPaginationed")
    List<Product> getProductsPaginated(@Argument("pageNumber") int pageNumber, @Argument("limit") int limit) {
        return this.productService.getProductsPaginated(pageNumber, limit);
    }
```

Below is the service code

```
public List<Product> getProductsPaginated(int pageNumber, int limit) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, limit);
    Page<Product> productPage = productRepo.findAll(pageable);
    retur
```

Below is the repository

```
@Repository 
public interface ProductRepo extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {
}
```

When I hit a pagination query spring JPA seems to be generating below query

```
select
    p1_0.product_id,
    p1_0.product_name,
    ....
    ....
from
    productmart.product p1_0 offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
```

This query doesn't work inside Redshift console also. The error I get is

```
Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "rows" 
Position: 1267;
```

Is there some way by which I can change the pagination query suffix?

Comment: Redshift doesn't support the OFFSET and FETCH FIRST clauses that are used by default in many databases supported by Spring Data JPA for pagination.

Comment: The generated query depends on the dialect. You are sure you have configured the correct dialect?

Comment: I tried explicitly specifying PostgreSQLDialect but it still generates the same `offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only` suffix. I tried other dialects too, even though it would be wrong, just to see if the query corrects. But to no avail!

Comment: As you can see Redshift isn't Postgres - similar but not the same.  In Redshift you will need to use cursors (DECLARE) and fetching (FETCH).  Does Spring support this?

Comment: @BillWeiner, yes I know that. But Redshift is based on Postgres, so tried Postgres dialect. Otherwise there isn't any proper dialect for Hibernate. What you are saying will work with native queries. That I can do by simply using `select * from xyz offset ? limit ?` type query. I was just trying to avoid that.

Comment: Have you looked into HibernateCursorItemReader?

Comment: that query does not look right, according to [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45622222/175554) we should use limit and offset for redshift and it looks like [supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66173960/175554), now I wonder what dialect did you set for your project, and can you share a reproducer ?